# SAP HCM Common Controller PersInfoWrapperController

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Dear SAP Fiori Experts

Can some one please advise on the issue I am facing. I am trying to extend a Standard HCM Fiori App - My Communication Data. The requirement is to add some validations to the input filed in one of the view when save button is pressed.

Unfortunately I am unable to find the respective controller to add the validation, the view is using a HCM commons controller "hcm.fab.lib.common.controller.PersInfoWrapperController" and can some one please advise where to add the custom code in this case and even the save button is also in the “sap.ushell.ui.footerbar” ? Thank you in advance.

View:[image]

**Project Structure:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view you are displaying in your screenshot is the “Display”-View and only contains labels and texts. So you cannot use this view for input validation.
The corresponding “Edit”-View, which you might want to use is "**99_Edit_Default_V001.view.xml**":
[image]

In this view, you will find the corresponding input fields.

Instead of using **PersInfoWrapperController** as mentioned by you, you might want to use therefore **PersInfoCommonCountryController**, as seen above.

This controller is found in the generic Service “**HCMFAB_COMMON**”, which is collectively used by all ESS apps together.
The **PersInfoCommonCountryController** is used for “Edit”-screens in all PersInfo apps. It provides a method “validateField”, which only checks required fields but not optional fields.

All fields with attribute **fieldGroupIds**="**PersInfoValidation**" are validated. In the SAP standard these are all input fields on screens delivered by SAP.
Controller-Hooks for customer specific extensions are currently not available.

One way to implement a customer specific input validation, could be to implement a customer specific “**CommonCountryController**” based on SAP’s generic **PersInfoCommonCountryController** – similar to the app-specific “**CommonCountryController**”:
[image]
The app-specific controller (marked with green color) needs to be replaced with your own customer specific controller.

In addition to this you need to provide your own customer-specific screen and reference there in the header under “controllerName” to your own customer-specific controller.

In order to get your customer-specific screen loaded, you need to create a customer-specific implementation of Enhancement Spot “**HCMFAB_PERSINFO**” in the backend – Country version would be “**99**”.

This implementation can inherit from class “**CL_IM_HCMFAB_PERSINFO_CONFIG99**”.

Method “**IF_EX_HCMFAB_PERSINFO_CONFIG~GET_SCREEN_VERSIONS**” needs to be redefined, to return your customer-specific screen for App ID “if_hcmfab_constants=>gc_application_id-mycommunication ('MYCOMMUNICATION')”:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @SAP Fiori Crew, this helped me. Sorry for the late response

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @SAP Fiori Crew, this helped me. Sorry for the late response